# Add attributes to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, datetime, inheritance, subclass

I have my own `DateTime` which is a subclass from `datetime.datetime`:

```
class DateTime(datetime.datetime):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.my_attr = kwargs.pop('my_attr')
        return datetime.datetime.__new__(cls, **kwargs)
```

When I create one or more instances each `instance.my_attr` points to the same object which is `cls.my_attr`:

```
>>> dt1 = DateTime(**{'year': 2014, 'month': 1, 'day': 17, 'hour': 18, 'minute': 10, 'my_attr': 'dt1'})
>>> dt1.my_attr
'dt1'
>>> dt2 = DateTime(**{'year': 2015, 'month': 2, 'day': 18, 'hour': 19, 'minute': 11, 'my_attr': 'dt2'})
>>> dt1.my_attr
'dt2'
>>> dt2.my_attr
'dt2'
>>> id(dt1.my_attr)
23429768
>>> id(dt2.my_attr)
23429768
>>> id(DateTime.my_attr)
23429768
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are changing attr of class not instance. You should create instance first and then assign attrib to it:

```
class DateTime(datetime.datetime):
    def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
       my_attr = kwargs.pop('my_attr')
       dt = datetime.datetime.__new__(cls, **kwargs)
       dt.my_attr = my_attr
       return dt
```

Test:

```
>>> dt1 = DateTime(**{'year': 2014, 'month': 1, 'day': 17, 'hour': 18, 'minute': 10, 'my_attr': 'dt1'})
>>> dt2 = DateTime(**{'year': 2015, 'month': 2, 'day': 18, 'hour': 19, 'minute': 11, 'my_attr': 'dt2'})
>>> dt1.my_attr
'dt1'
>>> dt2.my_attr
'dt2'
```